# Authorize the payment while creating payment on connected account and capture the funds later after connected account merchant submition

Tags: stripe-payments

I have Stripe Connect where I need the end customer to order services from a connected "custom" account. I want the direct charge to be made straight to the connected account. End customer is ordering his service a day in advance which means the end customer must authorize the payment while ordering where the payment will ofc be marked as uncaptured which I have successfully done. On the next day whenever the connect account merchant shows up and provides his services he must mark the job as done and of course must capture the payment of the end user. The problem is in the API where capturing the charge or paymentIntent error shows up that these does not exist ofc as the IDs are all from the connect account not from the platform. How can I capture these funds with a click of a button by providing paymentIntent or charge IDs from connect account because of course they dont exist on the platform. But the platform cloned the customer to the connected account...it cloned the payment method to the connected account....why cant the platform capture the funds later when it was the one who created it all in the first place? If this won't be possible how can I mimic this situation to keep the same logic of all payments?

API says you create the authorize with cloning the customer to connect account and use capture to false or caputre method to manual for the payment to be on hold.

```
$stripe->paymentIntents->create([
    'amount' => 1000,
    'customer' => cloned_customer_id,
    'payment_method' => cloned_payment_method,
    'currency' => 'usd',],
    'capture' => false,
  ['stripe_account' => '{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}']
);
```

Well after the job is done you want the merchant to click a button to capture the funds. Hes doing it on the platform using the platform keys. How to make it happen?

```
$stripe->paymentIntents('{{paymentIntent_ID}}'['{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}']);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are another square brackets in between is what finally helped. And stripe_account is the third parameter.

```
$stripe->paymentIntents->capture(
'{{PAYMENT_INTENT_ID}}',
[],
['stripe_account' => '{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}']
);
```

Comment: You’re right ! Apologies about the bad answer from earlier